# For scanning audio plugins what type of thread model in QT do I need to use?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I am working on a VST3 compatible plugin scanner, which basically looks for .vst3 files on the filesystem at predefined locations. Now if anybody answering this question has ever looked at a plugin scanner in a DAW, what it does basically is it has a table which has columns for plugin name, vendor, version, pathname etc. When it finds a plugin, it get all these details, populates the table one at a time. The Table will be in the GUI thread and the scanning will be done on a separate thread. Note that scanning is an expensive operation as it takes about 5-10 seconds per plugin at max. and a typical producer has about 100 plugins. Now how do I do that with Qt? I read the Threading Basics part (I am new to threading), it will be good if I can get it done with QtConcurrent class but I am not sure. Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question. My questions usually get answered only here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QtConcurrent seems the correct tool to get the job done without getting the hands too dirty with the low level details of threading.

My advice is to first design your data structures and GUI. For instance, your description would match a custom data class `AudioPluginsTableModel` (subclass of `QAbstractTableModel`) with a `QTableView` for representation and user interaction.

You may define a scanning function returning an instance of `AudioPluginsTableModel`, and execute this function with [QtConcurrent::run](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run) which would return a `QFuture<AudioPluginsTableModel>`, that you may watch for completion with `QFutureWatcher`.